# How is the new google logo (moving balls) implemented?

Tags: javascript, google-doodle

I got the code for the new google.com's doodle: http://gist.github.com/567948

The problem is, all the values in the `<div id="hplogo">` is changing dynamically, but not when I copy the code in my local machine.

It seems only JS + DIV, anything missing?

But now able to replicate it on my local machine.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of this logo.  Whats it for?  There is no tooltip or link...

Comment: @Blankasaurus: It's to celebrate Google's 12th birthday.

Comment: @Blankasaurus Just Google being Google

Comment: Is the logo supposed to be doing something? It's just an image no?

Comment: @Peter: Too bad you missed out on the fun. (Yes it does something)

Comment: @Blankasaurus thats just mean, what did it do then? :-) I have iGoogle on my homepage and use chrome, so I never go to the google homepage anymore

Comment: @Peter:  When you moved you mouse close to the logo the little bubbles scattered to avoid your mouse and then they settle back if you leave them alone.  They also got bigger as they moved away from their initial position.  It could take up the whole screen with the effect.  It was cool.

Comment: sound cool yeah :-) too bad I missed out

Comment: @Peter heres a link to the  [Particle Logo](http://www.google.com/logos/particle.html)

Comment: Thanks! It does look cool btw!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the source on github on line 153 says:

```
if (!v & amp; & amp; window.location.href.indexOf("#") == -1) {
```

it's supposed to be

```
if (!v && window.location.href.indexOf("#") == -1) {
```

Comment: It seems, http://jsbeautifier.org/ screwed the JS up, but it's still does not work. I will fix the JS everywhere and update the gist.

Comment: fixed, the culprit was firebug. I was copying JS from HTML edit tag mode.

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering, did you put  and  tags around it?  Seems to work fine on my Firefox 3.6.  I copied it to http://michaelhendrickx.com/googledots.html

I'm not sure what you mean with the "changing dynamically".  It seems to be the coordination values of the particles.

Comment: http://michaelhendrickx.com/googledots.html is not working on my browser. I am running Firefox 3.6.8 and Safari.